# Use a trigger to insert a new row after update?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to update a row without overwriting the previous information and insert a new row with updated data

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's called an after update trigger. There's an example of how to do this here:

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-update.shtml

So every time a row is updated in the table you create the trigger for, it will fire the trigger and perform any action you've specified (in your case inserting into another table (I guess you're looking to implement some sort of change tracking?) The original row that was updated won't be touched unless you specify so.

(General trigger documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)).

Comment: yeah i am implementing change tracking